# Can Mars provide vitamins?

Tags: mars, colonization, food

How long can nutrients found in Mars along with an algae diet sustain human life?

Comment: @uhoh maybe I should take this to worldbuilding?

Comment: That might be a very good idea for this particular question, yes.